# How do you store a GameScene so I can transition back to it from an InGame Menu?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Hello fellow programmers. Here is the scenario. There is an InGameMenuScene that the user can access during the game that allows them to access settings and such. One of the buttons, BackToGame, on the InGameMenuScene should take you back to the GameScene you were originally on. I'm needing help figuring out how to store a GameScene and then accessing stored GameScene when the BackToGame button is clicked. I tried storing it in the UserDefaults, but I'm having problems accessing it again in the InGameMenu.

Current GameScene:

```
func menuButtonPressed(){
let savedScene = BInNYGameScene.self
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefaults.set(savedScene, forKey: "CurrentScene")
    userDefaults.set(count, forKey: "CurrentCount")
    userDefaults.set(hitCount, forKey: "CurrentHitCount")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}
```

InGameMenuScene:

```
 func backToGame(){
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let backToGameScene = userDefaults.object(forKey: "CurrentScene") as! SKScene
    let nextScene = backToGameScene(size: scene!.size)
    nextScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)

}
```

Please let me know if there is a better way to store the GameScene and retrieving the GameScene. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of it in your MenuScene before you transition to it

Current GameScene:

```
func toMenu(){
    let menu = MenuScene(...)
    menu.previousScene = self
    scene?.view?.presentScene(self, transition: transition)

}
```

InGameMenuScene:

```
 weak var previousScene : SKScene?
 func backToGame(){
    guard let previousScene = previousScene else{fatalError("No previous scene provided")}
    scene?.view?.presentScene(previousScene, transition: transition)

}
```